# How to achieve cmake add_definitions in bazel?

Tags: cmake, bazel

I want to check is the machine have cuda support and have a flag `WITH_CUDA` in my code:

`#ifdef WITH_CUDA`

In cmake I can do something like

```
if(CUDA_LIBRARIES)
  add_definitions(-DWITH_CUDA)
```

How can I do this in bazel?

Comment: Removed c++ tag because this has nothing to do with c++